# how to use XPM file to make icons

Tags: linux, image, qt, icons

QT gui requires external icons. I was planning to use XPM file. Is it a good idea? Is there any manual or library for xpm to be installed into the Debian Stretch, i am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any image format, supported by Qt, in particular in XPM format may also be used. You should read QImage, QPixmap classes documentation.